# replace values in string

Tags: java, string

I have the following code and in need to replace the value on time from **PT14H01M00S** to **14:01:00**  the following code is omit the first two char but I get 14H01M00S ,there is no way to do that without using string builder?

```
String time = "PT14H01M00S";
String substring = time .substring(2);
substring.replace("H", ":");
substring.replace("M", ":");
substring.replace("S", "");

System.out.println(substring);
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to format a JodaTime Period into a different format. You should really be using the formatter given by JodaTime, rather than using String class API. See my answer for the correct way of doing this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to do

```
String time = "PT14H01M00S";
String substring = time .substring(2);
substring = substring.replace("H", ":");
substring = substring.replace("M", ":");
substring = substring.replace("S", "");

System.out.println(substring);
```

so the `substring` is not getting the new value returned from `replace` method

ran it in [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php) and got

[image]

Comment: Very similar to @Paniz answer!!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regex and replace

```
^..(\d\d)H(\d\d)M(\d\d)S$
```

with

```
$1:$2:$3
```

(I leave the details of the code as an exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to parse and format a [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html). You should not do it using the String class API. Use appropriate formatter already provided in JodaTime API.

You should build 2 [`PeriodFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html)s using [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html.html) class, one for parsing the given string into a `Period`, and then second for formatting the `Period` to the required format:

```
String periodString = "PT14H01M00S";

PeriodFormatter parser = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendLiteral("PT")
        .appendHours().appendSuffix("H")
        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("M")
        .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("S")
        .toFormatter();

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
        .printZeroAlways()
        .appendHours()
        .appendSeparator(":")
        .appendMinutes()
        .appendSeparator(":")
        .appendSeconds()
        .toFormatter();

System.out.println(formatter.print(parser.parsePeriod(periodString)));
```

**Output:**

```
14:01:00
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code instead :

```
 String time = "PT14H01M00S";
 String substring = time .substring(2);
 substring = substring.replace("H", ":");
 substring = substring.replace("M", ":");
 substring = substring.replace("S", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

I thinks this should work

```
String time = "PT14H01M00S".substring(2, time.length - 1).replace(/H|M/, ":");
```

Answer (score 2):

the `replace` method doesn't change the string it was called upon, it returns a new string.

So what you want is:

```
String time = "PT14H01M00S";
String substring = time .substring(2);
substring = substring.replace("H", ":");
substring = substring.replace("M", ":");
substring = substring.replace("S", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the use of [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to do this kind of tasks. They are very powerful to search and replace patterns of text.

Answer (score 2):

use this code instead

```
 String substring = time .substring(2);
 substring = substring.replaceAll("[HM]",":").replace("S", "");
```